# como obtener los minutos con decimales de segundos, javascript, timestamp?

Tags: javascript, timestamp

actualmente obtengo la diferencia de timestamp, dicha diferencia se comprende que es el timestamp de un valor minuto.

```
 vm.horario_firebase = data.val() + Date.now();
 let tiempo_faltante  = ultima_fecha_vecimiento-vm.horario_firebase ; //obteniendo la deferencia de timestamp
 console.log("ESTE ES EL TIEMPO QUE LE FALTA AL CRONOMETRO, TIMESTAMP");
 console.log(tiempo_faltante);
 let minutos = new Date(tiempo_faltante).getMinutes()*60/60; //De esta forma obtengo el valor del timestamp en minutos
 console.log("MINUTOS INGRESADOS");
 console.log(minutos); // 9 (valor de ejemplo, devuelve un entero)
```

El detalle que tengo es que en esa diferencia de timestamp, en su resta, existen segundos, entonces al momento de mostrar en la variable `minutos` muestra su valor en entero, como puedo obtener con su decimal, ejemplo, `9.5` lo cual equivaldría a 9 minutos con tantos segundos.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Multiplicar los minutos por 60 y dividirlos luego por 60 es lo mismo que multiplicar los minutos por 1, que a su vez es lo mismo que no multiplicarlos... por otro lado... estas haciendo un cronometro hacia atras??, es decir el usuario digita la cantidad de tiempo y te muestra esta información cada vez que avanzas en el tiempo?, nunca he visto el objeto o clase timestamp, pero se como se podria hacer  lo que necesitas con Date

Comment: Si no estoy mal el timeStamp tambien es un atributo función de algunas funciónes en javascript, este permite saber el numero de milisegundos desde el tiempo que fue creado el evento en el documento.

Comment: Tener en cuenta que Date, los datos numericos los devuelve como Int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De momento, esto es en lo que pude pensar:

```js
const texto = document.getElementById("texto");
const tiempo_total = parseInt(texto.textContent);
const initialData = new Date();
const minutosIniciales = initialData.getMinutes();
let minutos_restantes;

function getDifference(initialMinutes,initialMinutesData){

    const data = new Date();
    const actual_minutes = data.getMinutes();
    const actual_seconds = data.getSeconds();
    
    let floatDiff = Math.abs(initialMinutes - (actual_minutes - initialMinutesData));
    /*Esta operación hará que te muestre los decimales (Si los hay) del segundo en el que*/
    floatDiff -= (actual_seconds / 60);

    return floatDiff;
}

//Esta función es opcional pero la uso para obtener solo dos numeros apartir de la coma
function sliceFloatPoints(decimals,num){

    let result = 0;
    let stringNum = num.toString();
    let cutIndex = stringNum.indexOf(".");
    let currDecimals;
    let currLen;
    
    currDecimals = cutIndex !== -1 ? stringNum.slice(cutIndex + 1) : 0;
    currDecimals = currDecimals.length >= decimals ? currDecimals.slice(0, decimals) : currDecimals;
    currLen = currDecimals.length;
    result = cutIndex !== -1 ? parseInt(num.toString()) + (currDecimals / Math.pow(10,currLen)) : num;
    return result;
}

function calculate(){

    minutos_restantes = getDifference(tiempo_total,minutosIniciales);
    texto.textContent = sliceFloatPoints(2,minutos_restantes);/*Es opcional usar esta función, si quieres obtener 
                                                                todos los puntos decimales, coloca minutos_restantes
                                                                como valor*/

}

setInterval(calculate, 0);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Cronometro</title>
</head>
<body>
 <center><div class="texto" id = "texto">10</div></center>
</body>
</html>
```

El código lo que hace es que por medio de un elemento html obtiene el numero del cual va iniciar la cuenta regresiva, se inicia también otras variables iniciales de tiempo, estas se inician con el Objeto Date, ademas estas son estaticas, es decir nunca van a cambiar, esto debido a que necesitamos que este valor (cuantos minutos va a contar hacia atras),no cambie.

La función getDifference lo que hace es obtener la diferencia de tiempo que hay entre la primera y unica vez que fue inicializada la constante minutos_iniciales y los minutos transcurridos actualmente, luego resta a estos minutos (Que siempre los trae en enteros), los segundos faltantes (En forma de porcentaje, es decir de 0 a 100) para cambiar de un minuto a otro en cuenta regresiva, es decir: .98 significa que falta mucho para que los minutos decrementen, .01 significa que ya van a cambiar.

La función sliceFloatPoints, convierte el numero (De un montón de decimales), a los que necesitemos después de la coma, esto es por medio de la función slice, la cual permite crear un nuevo arreglo cortando desde ciertos puntos que le indiquemos a la función, si el limite final no es especificado como segundo parámetro en la función, esta devolverá un nuevo arreglo tomando como inicio el indice que le especificamos, apartir de este inicio tomara también todos los demás valores.

En nuestro caso, como no nos interesa la coma como valor decimal, lo que hacemos es que con la función indexOf, obtenemos el indice en el que se encuentra el carácter a buscar, en este caso la coma ("."), si esta es encontrada esta función retornara el indice donde se encuentra la coma, de lo contrario retornara -1, entonces ahora lo que se hace es (Si existe la coma decimal), simplemente con la función slice le damos como primer parámetro este indice obtenido + 1 (Ya que de no ser así estaríamos incluyendo de nuevo la coma), en caso de no existir coma decimal (Que el numero sea entero), simplemente no transformaremos el numero.

Una vez obtenida la parte flotante o decimal, simplemente usamos de nuevo esta función para acortar la cantidad de decimales obtenidos después de la coma a los que necesitemos en caso de que el numero no sea entero.

La función calculate, como dice su nombre, simplemente se encargara de asignar el tiempo faltante de la cuenta regresiva a una variable, luego lo muestra en pantalla.

¡Espero haya servido de algo la respuesta!, no se si es lo que necesitabas. mas eso entendi...